# Shorten multimensional array reference?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to output some information to an array from a multidimensional one referenced like this:

```
$adam_brown[$climbing][$punk]['woodwork'][1]['ID']
$adam_brown[$climbing][$punk]['cheese'][1]['Name']
$adam_brown[$climbing][$punk]['ruffian'][1]['ID']
```

This part will always be the same, so could I create a shorter, maybe one letter reference to it, e.g.:

```
$a = $adam_brown[$climbing][$punk]
```

Otherwise I am needlessly writing the same information several times

Then I could reference the above info like this:

```
$a['woodwork'][1]['ID']
```

Comment: `$a = &$adam_brown[$climbing][$punk];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to make a shorthand to the `$adam_brown[$climbing][$punk]`, just do it as you wrote:

```
$a = $adam_brown[$climbing][$punk];
```

However if you want to be able to modify the original array, you have tu use `&` reference:

```
$a = &$adam_brown[$climbing][$punk];
```

Documentation: [Returning References](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
$a = &$adam_brown[$climbing][$punk];
```